# Проверка в Edit Control, цвет текста

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

Как сделать проверку, чтобы при вводе в Edit Control определенного значения, оно становилось красным и нельзя было нажать на кнопку. То есть значение нужно изменить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно перегрузить OnCtlColor

```
HBRUSH MyDialogDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID()==IDC_EDIT1)//Тут id вашего EdibBox
    {
        CString text;
        GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1,text);
        if(text == "SomeText")
            pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255,0,0));
    }
    return hbr;
}
```

Более правильным решением было бы унаследоваться от стандартного EdibBox и написать свой MyEditBox и использовать потом его.

Comment: Это нужно перегружать в коде диалога или класса?

Comment: OnCtlColor нужно перегрузить в коде класса диалога где находится EditBox. При переписовке каждого контрола вызывается эта функция. Ловишь там свой EditBox и меняешь ему параметры.